# Batch, file copy and drag and drop bug

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

I've been looking around for an answer to this and nothing I found could actually solve my problem - sorry if there is already an answered post similar to this one that I didn't find.

Chapter 1)
I have a batch file that is supposed to copy any file/folder (recursively) to a specific folder in my USB flash drive. So, I wrote this:

```
echo Copying files...
xcopy /s /i %1 \folder\Subfolder\%1
```

This turns out swell if I call the batch file from the command line, but it stops working if I drag the object (file/folder) onto the .bat itself. I'm sure the shell must return an error message, but I can't read it, since the command line window closes instantaneously (that's why I ran it from the command line) as usual.

Can you help me fixing this?

Chapter 2)
I'd like the batch file to be able to distinguish from two situations:
a) Copying the file "C:\Document.doc" to "\folder\Subfolder"
b) Copying the file "C:\SomeFolder" to \folder\Subfolder\SomeFolder"

My code already does b), it just doesn't distinguish from a) and when I try to copy a single file what it does is this:
the instruction

```
xcopy /s /i %1 \Folder\SubFolder\%1
```

becomes

```
xcopy /s /i C:\Document.doc \Folder\SubFolder\C:\Document.doc
```

instead of

```
xcopy /s /i C:\Document.doc \Folder\SubFolder\Document.doc
```

How can I make the batch able to correct this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding a `pause` to the end of the batch file will keep the window open (so you can view errors) until you dismiss it.

Comment: please, can you give a example of what you want in situation A) and b) to update my answer? I can resolve it but i don't understand it, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

%1 has the absolute path of the file, so when you drag a file you are telling the CMD to do this:

```
xcopy  /S /i "C:\complete path of file\file.ext" "\folder\Subfolder\C:\complete path of file\file.ext"
```

You need to use the argument parameters to get the desired thing (absolute path, filename, extension, size of file, what you want)

like this:

```
xcopy /s /i "%~1" "\folder\Subfolder\%~nx1"
```

The example does:

```
xcopy  /S /i "C:\complete path of file\file.ext" "\folder\Subfolder\filename.ext"
```

But really you don't need to use the second argument, you can simplify as this:

```
xcopy /s /i "%~1" "\folder\Subfolder\"
```

Because the destiny filename by default takes the same name of the original file.